# Why can constant alpha be used for Q-Learning in practice?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, convergence

The convergence criteria of Q-Learning state that the learning rate parameter  $\alpha$ must satisfy the conditions:
$$\sum_k \alpha_{n^k(s,a)} =\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \sum_k \alpha_{n^k(s,a)}^{2} <\infty \quad \forall s \in \mathcal{S}$$
where $n_k(s,a)$ denotes the $k^\text{th}$ time $(s,a)$ is visited

Why can a constant $\alpha$ be used in practice?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?   There's nothing in the above two conditions that says $\alpha$ has to change as $n_k(s,a)$ changes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have also added $0 \leq \alpha_{n_k(s,a)}\leq 1$. If alpha is constant and non-zero then both sums diverge. I may be missing the point of what you are saying though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question can be asked in principle for any machine learning method. We almost never decay the step-size, and in fact we often use optimizers (like [ADAM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980)) that have errors in their proof of convergence. In fact, we continue to use ADAM instead of alternatives that correct this deficiency and provably converge ([see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09237)).

Why the discrepancy? Perhaps convergence is not something that matters *too much* in practice. It's still important to be sure, but I would rather have something that is quickly able to reach a small region of the optimum and never converge than something that guarantees convergence in an unachievable limit. I think this is the key point as well. An algorithm that converges with a decaying step-size will still get close to a local optimum with a constant step-size. However, the constant step-size will determine how close one can get before oscillating around said optimum.

The problem with such a set-up is that it is hard to analyze. What can be said about the finite-time analysis of algorithms in the average case? Not much. A convergence proof is easy to show in comparison.

You can also read a similar discussion in Chapter 2, page 33 of [Sutton's RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf). Although the chapter is on bandits and not on Q-learning, Sutton discusses that constant step-sizes can be good in non-stationary problems, where convergence is not really desirable.